# Running docker compose inside Docker Container

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, operating-system, dockerfile

I have a docker file I am building, it will use Localstack to spin up a mock AWS environment, at the minute I do this locally with my docker compose file, so I was thinking I could just copy my docker-compose.yml over when building my docker file and then run docker-compose up from dockerfile and I would be able to run my application from the container created from dockerfile

Here is the docker compose file

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    environment:
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
      - EDGE_PORT=4566
      - SERVICES=lambda,s3,cloudformation,sts,apigateway,iam,route53,dynamodb
    ports:
      - '4566-4597:4566-4597'
    volumes:
      - "${TEMPDIR:-/tmp/localstack}:/temp/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

Here us my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16-alpine

RUN apk update

RUN npm install -g serverless; \
    npm install -g serverless-localstack;

WORKDIR /app
COPY serverless.yml ./
COPY localstack_endpoints.json ./
COPY docker-compose.yml ./
COPY --from=library/docker:latest /usr/local/bin/docker /usr/bin/docker
COPY --from=docker/compose:latest /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose

EXPOSE 3000
RUN docker-compose up
CMD ["sls","deploy" ]
```

But the error I am receiving is

```
#17 0.710 Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?
#17 0.710 
#17 0.710 If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
```

I'm new to Docker, when i researched the error online I see people saying it needs to be run with Sudo, although I think in this case it is something to do with my volumes linking to the host running the container but really not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Docker container try to reach socket but it can not. so when you want to run your container use

```
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

it should fix the problem.

Comment: I get this error when I am building though with docker build -t serverless/docker . 
 not when i am running the container

Comment: I think maybe it is impossible in Dockerfiles. you can create a script with 
#! /bin/bash
docker-compose up -d
sls deploy

and share the socket as I said and run the script after you run the container

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, you can't do things in your Dockerfile that affect persistent state or processes running outside the container.  Imagine `docker build`ing your image, `docker push`ing it to a registry, and `docker pull`ing it on a new system; if the build step was able to start other running containers, they wouldn't be running with the same image on a different system.

At a more mechanical level, the build sequence doesn't have access to bind-mounted host directories or a variety of other runtime settings.  That's why you get the "couldn't connect to Docker daemon" message: the build container isn't running a Docker daemon and it doesn't have access to the host's daemon.

Rather than try to have a container embed the Compose tool and Compose setup, you might find it easier to just distribute a `docker-compose.yml` file, and make the standard way to run your composite application be running `docker-compose up` on the host.  Access to the Docker socket is incredibly powerful -- you can almost trivially use it to root the host -- and I wouldn't require it to avoid needing a fairly standard tool on the host.

Comment: I have a docker compose file it launches the mock DB then I can use my app with that locally, was hoping to create a container of my app and spin the mock DB up inside there. I suppose I could reference the hosts localhost for when i spin up my apps docker container rather than so a compose from inside it?

Comment: Can you launch both parts from the same `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: Well would I still need a docker file to create a container from my application? I build and run it with docker commands can that be done in docker compose file?